# JsonConvert not accepting stringify string

Tags: jquery, xml, asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

below is my stringify JSON data
`"{\"TimeSheet\":{\"TimeSheetDetail\":[{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Mon May 26 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"732\"},{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Tue May 27 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"732\"},{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Wed May 28 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"1281\"},{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Thu May 29 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"1281\"},{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Fri May 30 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"1281\"},{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Sat May 31 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"1281\"},{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Sun Jun 1 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"1281\"}]}}"`

in MVC I used the code below to modify the JSON data to XML

```
var doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{\"root\":[" + timeSheetJSon + "]}", "root");
```

XDocument.Parse(doc.InnerXml);

it returns as `<root><root>{"TimeSheet":{"TimeSheetDetail":[{"TimeSheetDetailsDate":"Mon May 26 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014","Hours":"732"},{"TimeSheetDetailsDate":"Tue May 27 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014","Hours":"732"},{"TimeSheetDetailsDate":"Wed May 28 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014","Hours":"1281"},{"TimeSheetDetailsDate":"Thu May 29 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014","Hours":"1281"},{"TimeSheetDetailsDate":"Fri May 30 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014","Hours":"1281"},{"TimeSheetDetailsDate":"Sat May 31 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014","Hours":"1281"},{"TimeSheetDetailsDate":"Sun Jun 1 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014","Hours":"1281"}]}}</root></root>`

But I need this is in XML format.
If there are any solution it would be great help.

Comment: You want the asp.net to return XML or convert JSON to XML in Javascript?

Comment: The posted sample works fine for me. The deserialization creates `XmlDocument`, and `XDocument.Parse` creates `XDocument`. Both are in corretc format. Tested with JSON.NET version 6.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[TestMethod]
public void ConvertJsonToXml()
{
    string json = "{\"TimeSheet\":{\"TimeSheetDetail\":[{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Mon May 26 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"732\"},{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Tue May 27 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"732\"},{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Wed May 28 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"1281\"},{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Thu May 29 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"1281\"},{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Fri May 30 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"1281\"},{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Sat May 31 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"1281\"},{\"TimeSheetDetailsDate\":\"Sun Jun 1 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014\",\"Hours\":\"1281\"}]}}";
    var xdoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json);
    var xml = xdoc.ToString();
    Assert.IsNotNull(xml);
}
```

xml result:

```
<TimeSheet>
  <TimeSheetDetail>
    <TimeSheetDetailsDate>Mon May 26 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014</TimeSheetDetailsDate>
    <Hours>732</Hours>
  </TimeSheetDetail>
  <TimeSheetDetail>
    <TimeSheetDetailsDate>Tue May 27 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014</TimeSheetDetailsDate>
    <Hours>732</Hours>
  </TimeSheetDetail>
  <TimeSheetDetail>
    <TimeSheetDetailsDate>Wed May 28 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014</TimeSheetDetailsDate>
    <Hours>1281</Hours>
  </TimeSheetDetail>
  <TimeSheetDetail>
    <TimeSheetDetailsDate>Thu May 29 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014</TimeSheetDetailsDate>
    <Hours>1281</Hours>
  </TimeSheetDetail>
  <TimeSheetDetail>
    <TimeSheetDetailsDate>Fri May 30 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014</TimeSheetDetailsDate>
    <Hours>1281</Hours>
  </TimeSheetDetail>
  <TimeSheetDetail>
    <TimeSheetDetailsDate>Sat May 31 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014</TimeSheetDetailsDate>
    <Hours>1281</Hours>
  </TimeSheetDetail>
  <TimeSheetDetail>
    <TimeSheetDetailsDate>Sun Jun 1 00:00:00 UTC+0530 2014</TimeSheetDetailsDate>
    <Hours>1281</Hours>
  </TimeSheetDetail>
</TimeSheet>
```